# vba date comparison

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access table where dates are stored in the format "25102010". How can I compare this to today's date? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you todays date formatted as you have above

```
Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")
```

Comment: there are 1400 people on SO subscribed to the "VBA" tag. Asking here is just fine.

Comment: no problem... just letting them know about the other resource if they hadn't found it yet. I reworded it, I didn't mean for it to imply that they shouldn't post here.

Comment: VBA is programming or programming related. This forum is more appropriate than SuperUser.

Comment: In fact, VBA questions on SuperUser should be closed and migrated, as per this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750990/create-sheets-and-move-data-based-on-unique-items-in-a-specific-column-using-exc, so I think you should revise your question.