# How to copy different text strings and paste into new Sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA programming, and I need some help writing a simple macro in Excel 2010.

Here is the problem: There are about 20 string texts (items) in Column A, which are repeated over and over, i.e. Worksheet has 5 columns and about 20000 rows (the number of rows could expand later), and these items are repeated in column A every about 20th or 21st row.

Now, it should be possible, with help of a macro, to search for each item (text string) in Column A and if that string is found within the cell, cut and paste that cell's entire row into another sheet in the workbook. This should be done for every 20 item. It means, at the end, after using the macro, there are 20 added new sheets, containing all of the same items, the names of sheets are also that specific item.

Hopefully that’s clear, what I’m looking for!
I could find some codes to search one item and copy/paste it into a new sheet, but I cannot do this for every 20 items within just one macro. So I’d be glad, if someone could help!
Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Search()
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim MyArr As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NewSh As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    MyArr = Array("PI18303")
    Set NewSh = Worksheets.Add
    NewSh.Name = "PI18303"

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z100000")
        Rcount = 0
        For i = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(i), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Do
                    Rcount = Rcount + 1
                    Rng.Copy NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount)
                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried a loop to do this?

Comment: You need to paste what code you have. Show us your effort. We like to fix specific problems in YOUR code. We don't like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Hi D_Bester, this is what I have now (I'll post it in a new comment now). This is just for one item, now I want to do this for 19 other items!

Comment: You can delete your comments with code; it should be in with the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another post that might do what you want; [please check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750990/create-sheets-and-move-data-based-on-unique-items-in-a-specific-column-using-ex/4753258#4753258). But instead of looking for a header you need to look for Column A.

```
'change this: Set rLNColumn = sh.UsedRange.Find(sLNHEADER, , xlValues, xlWhole)
'to this:
Set rLNColumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z100000")
```

That should get you close.

Comment: Hi D_Bester, thanks for your edit and answer! Unfortunately, the linked code doesn't work! 
And the other problem is, that I can search only for one item, now, for example, I want to find "FIR18" after "PI18303"! 
I cannot write that part...